# Can we deduce if a set is measurable, given a measurable function and a measurable space?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $f(x):X\rightarrow Y $, where $X$ is a measurable space. Suppose that $f$ is measurable. Let $E$ be a subset of $X$. Now, suppose that $f(E)$ is closed or clopen. Can we deduce that $E$ is a measurable set?

I am asking this question because Rudin's definition of measurable functions depends on open sets in the range of $f$. Rudin's definition for measurable functions is:

"If $X$ is a measurable space, $Y$ is a topological space, and $f$ is a mapping of $X$ into $Y$, then $f$ is said to be measurable provided that $f^{-1}(V)$ is a measurable set in $X$ for every open set $V$ in $Y$.

I would think that the answer would be no. However, I am unable to come up with a rigorous logic as to why. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If $f$ is constant, then you can deduce almost nothing about $E$ from $f(E)$ (exactly, the only thing you **can** deduce is whether $E \neq \emptyset$).

Comment: Do you understand why Rudin's definition depends on open sets in the codomain?

Comment: @user46944 I would think that the reason is because this construction fits better with the integration method that is exposed in the book. However, I am not so sure. Why?

Comment: @user97554 Well, in general we say if $(X, \Sigma)$ and $(Y, \tau)$ are measurable spaces (i.e., $\Sigma$ and $\tau$ are $\sigma$-algebras), then $f: X \to Y$ is *measurable* if $f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma$ for each $E \in \tau$.  Nothing changes with this definition using open sets.  First of all, $Y$, the codomain, is a topological space, so we can talk about convergence (i.e., the convergence of a sequence of measurable functions) since there are open sets.  That's why are are considering $\tau$ as the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ (the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets).

Comment: @user97554 Now, it's easy using some elementary set theory to prove that $f^{-1}( \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_{i}) =  \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} f^{-1}(A_{i})$ and $f^{-1}( \bigcap \limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_{i}) =  \bigcap \limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} f^{-1}(A_{i})$, and also $f^{-1}(A^{c}) = (f^{-1}(A))^{c}$.  Because of these facts that you should prove, the set $\{E \mid f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $Y$.  If we can show this set contains all of the open sets, then it is a $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$ that contains all of the open sets.

Comment: @user97554 Since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is *generated* by the open sets, i.e., it is the *smallest* $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets, it would have to be that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is contained in $\{ E \mid f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma \}$ *if* this $\sigma$-algebra contains the open sets.  So by checking only that the preimage of open sets is measurable, we immediately get that the preimage of any Borel set (i.e., measurable set in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) is measurable.  So this idea of checking open sets for measurability doesn't stray from the original definition of

Comment: @user97554 ...measurability where the preimage of each measurable set is measurable.  It's just that we have to check only the open sets because once we do, we get the other sets for free by the argument above.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. It depends on which $\sigma$-algebra equips the measurable space.

Rudin's definition relies on the fact that if $Y$ is a topological space, we usually equip it with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, which is generated by open sets.

Comment: Is there a proof or a reference I could look up to verify this?